# Querying an array of participant through concepts

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

This is what my model file looks like.

```
participant Doctor identified by doctorID {
o String doctorID
o String contact 
o String doctorName
o String description
--> Schedule schedule
}

asset Schedule identified by scheduleID{
 o String scheduleID
 o Day availableDays 

}

concept Time{
--> Doctor[] AM00
--> Doctor[] AM01
--> Doctor[] AM02
--> Doctor[] AM03 
--> Doctor[] AM04 
--> Doctor[] AM05 
--> Doctor[] AM06
--> Doctor[] AM07 
--> Doctor[] AM08
--> Doctor[] AM09 
--> Doctor[] AM10 
--> Doctor[] AM11 
--> Doctor[] PM00
--> Doctor[] PM01
--> Doctor[] PM02
--> Doctor[] PM03 
--> Doctor[] PM04 
--> Doctor[] PM05 
--> Doctor[] PM06 
--> Doctor[] PM07 
--> Doctor[] PM08 
--> Doctor[] PM09 
--> Doctor[] PM10 
--> Doctor[] PM11
 }
concept Day{
o Time  monday
o Time  tuesday
o Time  wednesday
o Time  thursday
o Time  friday
o Time  saturday
o Time  sunday
}
```

I'm trying to write a query that will display all the available doctors at a specific hour. For example, if I'm looking for doctors on Monday at 00 AM, then the doctor array of AM00 should be returned.

I'm trying something like this

```
query getAvailableDoctors {
description: "Returns a list of doctors available at a specific hour"
statement:
  SELECT org.acme.Doctor
  FROM org.acme.Schedule
  WHERE (schedule.availableDays.monday.AM00 CONTAINS('resource:org.acme.Doctor') )
}
```

But all this does is return NULL, when there are infact doctors stored in the AM00 array. Am I doing this wrong? Or is there a better way to query this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following [model, query definition etc] as shown below - its based on the fact that you went the 'concept' route (you could also use plain arrays too and query an array of Days/Hours, slightly different model but that's for another day). Your query (above) wouldn't work because you can't 'step' through the objects in the definition of your query - its not like an SQL database (just to clear that up).

The model below provides the concept `Availability` to capture the doctor's availability matrix, in the asset `Schedule` (hence the relationship to doctor there). Furthermore, it is an array of concepts, allowing for hourly schedules within each day for that schedule ID. Finally, a doctor (or an array of doctors) - can be associated with that Schedule - if its one-to-one, then obviously you only need to supply one 'doctor' entry. See my sample JSON data for `schedule` further down below. Likewise, a doctor (Participant) can have a relationship to one or more schedules (or not, as the case may be - the option is there anyway  - as you'll see in the `Doctor` participant, I have an optional `schedule` (an array of schedules) - in this case it would store the concept data (inside the asset) on the actual participant record (then you would query that instead) - but you might not want to manage schedule data inside the participant for obvious reasons). Note: this is just one suggestion, based on what you posted - there are many ways to peel an orange :-)

```
participant Doctor identified by doctorID {
o String doctorID
o String contact 
o String doctorName
o String description
o Schedule[] schedule optional // see comment below
}

asset Schedule identified by scheduleID {
 o String scheduleID
 o Availability[] availability
 --> Doctor[] doctor
}

concept Availability {
o WeekDay Day 
o Hours Hour 
}

enum WeekDay {
o MON
o TUE
o WED
o THU
o FRI
o SAT
o SUN
}

enum Hours {
o H00
o H01
o H02
o H03
o H04
o H05
o H06
o H07
o H08
o H09
o H10
o H11
o H12
o H13
o H14
o H15
o H16
o H17
o H18
o H19
o H20
o H21
o H22
o H23

}
```

With that model, you can now define your Concept query.

Example 1:

```
query doctordoctor1 { 
  description: "Select all doctors available at 1st hour on MON only" 
  statement: SELECT org.acme.mynetwork.Schedule 
  WHERE ( availability CONTAINS (Day == "MON" AND Hour == "H01" )   ) 
}
```

will return Schedule #4 only and therefore Doctors #1 and #2 (and not Doctors 3 or 4)

Example 2:

```
query doctordoctor2 { 
  description: "Select all doctors available at 1st hour - any day" 
  statement: SELECT org.acme.mynetwork.Schedule 
  WHERE ( availability CONTAINS (Hour == "H01" )   ) 
}
```

will return Schedule #4 and #5 which means Doctors #1 and #2  - plus - Doctors #3 and #4 will all match.

Pls note it will NOT return the detail of the Doctor's profile in that query pls note - you can call the query in a transaction, and then get the related Doctor info (ie if required) for each doctor found, by the fact there is a relationship from the returned query object (the schedule).

=================== DATA ========= (left here, but could put in pastebin)

```
{
  "$class": "org.acme.mynetwork.Schedule",
  "scheduleID": "4",
  "availability": [
    {
      "$class": "org.acme.mynetwork.Availability",
      "Day": "MON",
      "Hour": "H01"
    },
    {
      "$class": "org.acme.mynetwork.Availability",
      "Day": "MON",
      "Hour": "H02"
    },
    {
      "$class": "org.acme.mynetwork.Availability",
      "Day": "MON",
      "Hour": "H03"
    },
    {
      "$class": "org.acme.mynetwork.Availability",
      "Day": "TUE",
      "Hour": "H04"
    },
    {
      "$class": "org.acme.mynetwork.Availability",
      "Day": "TUE",
      "Hour": "H05"
    },
    {
      "$class": "org.acme.mynetwork.Availability",
      "Day": "TUE",
      "Hour": "H06"
    }
  ],
  "doctor": [
    "resource:org.acme.mynetwork.Doctor#1",
    "resource:org.acme.mynetwork.Doctor#2"
  ]
}
```

next item

```
{
  "$class": "org.acme.mynetwork.Schedule",
  "scheduleID": "5",
  "availability": [
    {
      "$class": "org.acme.mynetwork.Availability",
      "Day": "WED",
      "Hour": "H01"
    },
    {
      "$class": "org.acme.mynetwork.Availability",
      "Day": "WED",
      "Hour": "H02"
    },
    {
      "$class": "org.acme.mynetwork.Availability",
      "Day": "THU",
      "Hour": "H03"
    },
    {
      "$class": "org.acme.mynetwork.Availability",
      "Day": "FRI",
      "Hour": "H04"
    },
    {
      "$class": "org.acme.mynetwork.Availability",
      "Day": "SAT",
      "Hour": "H05"
    },
    {
      "$class": "org.acme.mynetwork.Availability",
      "Day": "SAT",
      "Hour": "H06"
    }
  ],
  "doctor": [
    "resource:org.acme.mynetwork.Doctor#3",
    "resource:org.acme.mynetwork.Doctor#4"
  ]
}
```

==== CODE to call the query from a transaction processor - or else just call it

from the REST API

```
/**
 * Track the schedule
 * @param {org.acme.mynetwork.doctor} doctor - the query object as a trxn
 * @transaction
 */

function doctor(doctor) {

  console.log('got inside doctor function');
  return query('doctordoctor') // 
        .then(function (results) {

           var schedule_asset = [];
           for (var n = 0; n < results.length; n++) {
                   var schedule_asset = results[n];
                   console.log('The transaction object ' + (n+1) + ', object is ' +  schedule_asset);
                   console.log('Schedule identifier is: ' + schedule_asset.getIdentifier()); 
                   console.log(' Doctor id is ' + schedule_asset.doctor[0].getIdentifier()); 


           }

      });  

}
```

Comment: Thank you Paul for such an amazing detailed answer.

Comment: I have made changes to the model such that every schedule asset has a relationship with only a single doctor. Now when I run the query in code, I get a list of all schedule assets that are available at that time. In your code after running query you're simply displaying results on the screen. What I want to do is make an array of IDs of the doctors that are available and then return them. How can this be done?

Comment: using `schedule_asset` array defined above ; you would simply add each doctor ID found as `schedule_asset.push(results[n].doctor.getIdentifier());` - based on the fact you now only have a single doctor ie `--> Doctor doctor` relationship in your Schedule modeled asset. So that's how you can push the list of IDs onto the array, and use that after the `for` loop closes out. Make sense?

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. But what do I do after the for loop closes? I want to return this array of doctor ids to my front-end app that called this transaction function. But according to my understanding, a transaction is always supposed to return a promise. Currently, when I return the schedule_asset as it is after the for loop I get this error at runtime `status: 500, message: ReferenceError: identifier 'schedule_asset' undefined`

Comment: Given your last Q: From your front-end app, you can simply make a REST API endpoint call on the defined query and process the results in your front-end app using tables etc . Eg. using  `request.get` etc to return  results etc request.get('http://localhost:3000/api/queries/myQuery' ) . More info here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/call-out